# Инициализация слайдера после попадания его в поле видимости (в следствии прокрутки страницы)

Tags: jquery

Есть страницы (условно - высота 1800px). В самом низу страницы находится слайдер с изображениями. На данный момент его html-код такой:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider_wrap">
    <div id="slides">       
        <img src="/img/slider/1.jpg" />
        <img src="/img/slider/2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span class="next"></span><span class="prev"></span>
</div>
```

При открытии страницы загружаются первые два изображения, остальные подгружаются по мере просмотра слайдера.

Внимание, вопрос:
как сделать, чтобы слайдер начинал свою работу только после того, как страница прокручена вниз и поле, где будет сам слайдер, появилось на экране? То бишь, первые 2 картинки должны подгружаться только после того, как до самого слайдера добрались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй отловить позицию скролла [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) через событие [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). И лишь при достижении определенной позиции запускать слайдер

Comment: Да, спасибо. Именно так я и сделал уже.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {              
        var pageY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        heightScreen = window.innerHeight + pageY;
        sliderTopY = $("#slides").offset().top;
        if ((heightScreen > (sliderTopY - sliderTopY * 0.05)) && loadSlider) {
            loadSlider = 0;
        } 
    }
```